# Как сделать асинхронное неблокирующее чтение с ожиданием результата?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть задача: загрузить данные из таблицы БД в DataTable. Так как данных достаточно много и сервер зело задумчивый, собираюсь воспользоваться асинхронными методами, но почему-то ничего не работает как заявлено.
Есть такой код:

```
public void LoadData()
{
 LoadDataAsync();
}

protected async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
  // какой-то подготавливающий код - неинтересные, скучные подробности
  await _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);
  // другой код, установка переменных и прочие действия
}
```

После вызова LoadData() вторая часть метода LoadDataAsync() просто не выполняется и выполнение передается в функцию, которая вызывала LoadData(). И, значит, таблица пуста.
Пробовал так:

```
public async void LoadData()
{
 await LoadDataAsync();
}
```

Создавал Task-и и вызывал через Run с await-ом и через await Task.WhenAll(t) в обоих методах, один делал с префиксом async, второй нет, пробовал разные их комбинации. Пока добился ожидания следующим образом:

```
public void LoadData()
{
 Task _res = Task.Run(LoadDataAsync);
 Task.WaitAll(_res);
}
```

Код для LoadDataAsync() как показан выше.

Отсюда вопрос: как сделать корректно загрузку данных, чтобы не было блокировки и организовать ожидание загрузки данных в память?

Спасибо

Comment: Что заметил, при отладке в методе LoadDataAsync() после await код никогда не выполняется. Даже, если я ставлю в потоке UI Task.Delay() туда выполнение не приходит

Comment: Откуда вы вызываете `LoadData()`? Из команды, обработчика события? Сейчас не понятно, как это ожидать без блокирования текущего потока. Сам же вызов `LoadDataAsync()` ничего не ожидает. Покажите весь ваш скучный код вместе с тем, где вызывается `LoadData()`.

Comment: На данный момент эта функция вызывается из конструктора. Но при необходимости обновления возможен прямой вызов. Данный класс является хранилищем справочных данных из БД. Скучный код - это загрузка SQL запроса, подготовка компонентов к работе, собственно сама загрузка показана в листинге, вторая часть - установка переменных (флагов) о готовности, обработка загруженных данных

Comment: Что ещё обнаружил: если код LoadData() сделать синхронным типа Task, а LoadDataAsync(), наоборот не синхронным и убрать из него await, то всё начинает работать корректно. Теперь не понимаю почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> На данный момент эта функция вызывается из конструктора.

В конструктор нельзя вставлять свой код из-за всякого рода ограничений, связанных с не до конца проинициализированным окном на момент выполнения конструктора. Вместо конструктора используйте событие `Window.Loaded` и его обработчик, и в нём уже можно сразу использовать асинхронность.

```csharp
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // здесь можно сделать что-то до начала загрузки
    await LoadDataAsync();
    // здесь что-то после, можно взаимодействовать с контролами
}

private async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    // ...
    await _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);
    // ...
}
```

Перенесите весь свой код из конструктора в обработчик события `Window.Loaded`, оставьте в конструкторе только родной `InitializeComponent()`.

Еще почитайте [эту статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

---

Если же вы просто хотите запустить параллельную загрузку, то это можно сделать без асинхронности, а просто запуском задачи.

```csharp
private void LoadData()
{
    // ...
    _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable).Wait();
    // ...
}
```

Вызов

```csharp
Task.Run(() => LoadData());
```

Comment: Я имел в виду конструктор данного класса. Обычно в конструкторе окна у меня идет стандартный InitializeComponent() и привязка DataContext (после инициализации). Этот класс заводится из App.cs

Comment: @АртемийСоболев если вы заводите класс из App.cs, то вам не нужно взаимодействовать с интерфейсом при загрузке данных, так? Тогда чего вам надо ожидать? Вызывайте из конструктора просто `LoadDataAsync()` тогда.

Comment: @АртемийСоболев дополнил ответ.

Comment: То есть, можно ограничиться только одним await, и не греть мозг. Этот класс будет жить на протяжении всей работы приложения, так как он хранит информацию справочника (таких классов будет несколько), и VM впоследствии к этому классу будет обращаться за данными конкретного справочника. Почему запускаю асинхронно, чтобы можно было несколько таких классов одновременно запустить, и ускорить загрузку приложения. Спасибо за разъяснения, оставлю как получилось